# Workflow Email Not Sending to Some Recipients

Tags: designer-workflow, email, person

I'm having an issue that I hope you guys can help with.  I have a simple workflow that kicks off every time a particular user makes an edit to the list.  Within the list, I have a field that is a "person or group" field that contains about 10 registered persons of my site.  When the user makes the edit to the list, the person that is selected in this particular field is sent an automated email from the workflow.

For the past few times that this workflow has kicked off, an email has gone out to the person listed in the field of the edited item.  However, two members in the group have not been receiving their emails.

So for example yesterday:

1. User made edit to list to edit 3 line items.
2. Recipient A in the "Person" field of the first edited line item was sent an automated email to let them know the item was edited.
3. Recipient B in the "Person" field of the second edited line item was sent an automated email to let them know the item was edited.
4. Recipient C in the "Person" field of the third edited line item DID NOT receive their automated email.
5. I have written the workflow to cc me on these automated emails, so for the first two recipients, I received the email and see that they were the main recipient of the email with me as the cc.  For Recipient C though, the email I received shows the "To" field as empty with myself listed as the cc.

Anyone know what's going on here and how to fix it?  Obviously my workflow is working as intended for the other recipients, but it is not working for a couple people.  I have tried adding a lookup within the body of the email itself to see if there is an issue with the person's accounts in the Person field, and it shows the recipients' names in the email body no problem, it's just not populating the "To" field of the email with their email and it's only happening for a couple persons within the group.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: I would start by double-checking the user profiles for the users who aren't getting emails. It sounds like the Work Email property isn't populated. If that doesn't seem to be the problem, then I would try a test workflow with a Send Email action with the recipient hard-coded in and see if they get that. If they don't, there's a problem with their email property. If they do, there's more likely a problem with the workflow, and I'd try logging the user profile properties in the workflow to debug. Let me know if you need help with any of these steps.